# Cordova App not compatible with some android tablets

Tags: android, cordova, tablet

I built an app using sencha touch and Cordova 2.7.0. It runs on phones but some tablets (e.g. 10.1" Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 - GT-P5110) are marked as not supported in the play store. The tablet I mentioned runs android 4.0.3 (so api level is ok) but it's even not listed in play store's list of ALL devices.

If I put the app to alpha state, the tablet is able to download and install it, but not at production state.

Screenshots for all resolutions are included, start screen for normal, hdpi, ldpi, mdpi and xhdpi as well. The manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  package="a.b.c" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="15" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largestWidthLimitDp="2560" android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="2560" android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="240"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="MyApp" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Do you have any idea, why the app is not supported for (some) tablets? Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be the `minSdkVersion=9`. Some tablets were released with androids 2.2 and lower too.

It's not hard to find tablets running android 1.5 like [this one.](http://dx.com/p/7-touch-screen-tft-lcd-google-android-1-5-tablet-pc-w-wifi-camera-arm926eh-s-rev5-37867)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try it but meanwhile a new test version got online and for some reason now it works. It's a tablet-only version and I only set all android:xxxScreens to false excepting xlargeScreens. The 3 settings after xlargeScreen seem to be important as well. However I'll check your tip - thank you :)

Comment: Good to know its work, but your range of target is too large. Later please use lower range target and min for less deployment problem.